# Performance comparison for Service Bus message handlers

Tags: azure-functions, azure-service-fabric, azure-eventgrid

I'm looking for advice for best approaches for handling Service Bus messages, at scale, comparing performance to cost.

Currently, we're using Service Fabric to handle the Service Bus messages, which works very well, but requires an always-on cluster of Service Fabric VMs.  With occasional usage, this ends up adding more cost for the overall solution vs serverless approaches.

I'm considering moving to Azure Functions for these message handlers, either directly with Service Bus binding, or via Event Grid.

If anyone has compared these various options, and tested performance of message handling, I'd be very interested to hear feedback.

My concern would be latency in message handling, and wondering if Event Grid is overkill for having a single subscriber to Service Bus messages.

Would it be correct that Service Fabric, Azure Function Trigger, and Event Grid would be the best-to-worst performing options in that order?

Comment: Could you describe what are you expecting from the Event Grid for handling SB messages? It looks like, you want to keep a publisher side the same such as a sender of the SB messages, right?

Comment: I’d be looking to invoke an Azure Function to handle the incoming Service Bus message, in a way which auto scales to handle increased load.  The sender of the Service Bus message is an ASP.NET Core API, and I want to offload some background processing into serverless Functions.  Since you can already trigger a Function directly from a Service Bus message, I wasn’t clear if there was any value of going thru Event Grid in this situation.

Comment: The *Event Grid* can help to notify immediately a situation at the SB entity, where a message is arriving and there is no active listener, also periodically 120 seconds notified that the message(s) is/are there and still no active listener. I can see, the Event Grid SB subscriber (the SB message receiver) can help resolving some situation during the "cold start function" etc. in other words, in the situations where is no active listener on the SB entity.

Comment: In addition to my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061055/wake-up-time-of-azure-function-triggered-by-service-bus-queue